# How to get Login token callback back to Gmail addon using Appscript

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script

I am creating A login functionality in gmail addon and I created Login callback in webapp but I am not able to understand how to get the login token back to addon from the Login Successful URL where I am returning the token.

Here the Login Code where I am getting the callback token:

```
var SCRIPT_ID = "MY_SCRIPT_ID";

// get a callback url to render in popup
function getAuthURL() {  
  var authorizeURL = getCallbackURL('testCallback');
  return authorizeURL;
}

// generate a user callback url
function getCallbackURL(callback) {
  var state = "ScriptApp.newStateToken().withTimeout(3600).withMethod(callback).createToken()";
  return 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/'+SCRIPT_ID+'/usercallback?state='+state;
}

// generate login 
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createTemplate(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script>
          function openSeparatePopup() {
          var url = encodeURIComponent('<?= getAuthURL() ?>');
            var popupOptions = "width=500,height=600";
            var separatePopup = window.open('https://url.com/addon_login/?client=gmailaddon&redirect_url=' + url, "SeparatePopupWindow", popupOptions);
          }

          // Listen for messages from the separate popup window
          window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            if (event.data.action) {
              console.warn(event.data.value);
              
            }
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <button onclick="openSeparatePopup()">Login</button>
      </body>
    </html>
  `).evaluate();
}
```

I will be getting the callback like: [https://script.google.com/macros/d/'+SCRIPT_ID+'/usercallback?state='rfbjkbgjhybgrfbgiurghr&token=hfgrbiguirghiburdgukrtb487t4ibr](https://script.google.com/macros/d/%27+SCRIPT_ID+%27/usercallback?state=%27rfbjkbgjhybgrfbgiurghr&token=hfgrbiguirghiburdgukrtb487t4ibr)

I need this token part back to my addon where i can store it in userProerties.

I am Not able to get the token back to addon from the URL.

Comment: Not sure what you asking but maybe you can use the withSuccessHandler

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more of what you are trying to do? ie when a user clicks on the login button, what happens and what are you expecting the journey of the token to be?